# Configure SparkPost account in test server

Tags: email, laravel-5, sparkpost, laravel-mail

I have a Laravel 5.2 application, I need to send emails so I choose SparkPost as mail service. I configured the api_key, the driver, etc. But now I get this error:

```
Client error: `POST https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{ "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid domain", "description": "No sending domain specified", "code": "7001" } ] }
```

I read that's because an invalid domain, so, it's not clear to me how to configure the domain if I don't have a domain, I just have a test server with an IP address 45.xxx.xxx.xxx or which options do I have to send mails?

Answer (score 1):

You can test your system with add this to every email:

```
email + '.sink.sparkpostmail.com'
```

And I guess you also need add your domain. It is a domain of your FROM-email.

https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2560839-how-do-i-test-using-the-sink-server-on-sparkpost

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `content.from` field of your request is empty or missing.

The SparkPost transmissions endpoint expects `content.from` to contain an email address using a domain you own. That address then appears in the `From:` header of each email you send.

The usual path is to [create a sending domain](https://app.sparkpost.com/account/sending-domains) for this purpose on your account. [Here's an article on how to do that](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1933318-creating-sending-domains).

For a quick test, you can use an address under the `@sparkpostbox.com` sandbox domain. *Caveat: your account is limited to 50 emails addressed from sparkpostbox.com for the life of your account.*